# AndroidのURLオブジェクト生成時のクエスチョンマーク

Tags: android, java, http, url

Androidアプリを作成しており、HttpURLConnectionを使ってhttpリクエストを飛ばします。
このとき、手前でURLオブジェクトを生成するのですが、クエスチョンマーク(?)が無視されてしまいます。
SampleCode

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.1:80//hoge.cgi?")
```

上記コードの結果、urlは"http://192.168.1.1:80//hoge.cgi"となりクエスチョンマークが省かれてしまいます。
何か対策はありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `?`はそれ以降がクエリストリングであることを示す文字です。クエリストリングが無いので（つまり`?`は必要ないの）、無視されるのだと思いますが、どういった理由で`?`を付加したいのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。リクエスト先であるサーバー側の仕様で対象のcgiコマンドに"?"が必要となっています。確かに、本来はクエリストリングを以降に付加するために"?"をつけるはずですが、サーバー側が何故かクエリストリングなしでも"?"が必要な仕様になっています。

Comment: もう少し具体的な内容を記載できないでしょうか？ソースコードの抜粋と、何を確認して「クエスチョンマークが省かれている」と判断したのか、よく分かりませんでした。例えば、変数`url`を`System.out.print(url);`した結果に`?`が無かったとか。